# Is REST API available to apply TFS Git branch policies to git branches

Tags: git, rest, api, tfs, branch

I have about 30-40 git repositories in TFS Git.  I would like to apply branch policies to the 'master' branch only, but I do not want to manually do this to each git repo.  I value my time.  I know about the TFS REST API, but I cannot find anything to apply policies to branches in a git repository.  Can I use the .NET C# API to do this?  If so, are there any examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no TFS REST API and .Net object API about Git branch policy currently. You need to add branch policy for your branch manually.

You could vote this uservoice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17039236-tfs-api-for-git-branch-policy